# Camera for cross-platform (xamarin)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So far I managed to use camera for my android application by following [this android guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/).

However, I also need to use camera on other platform as well. But I couldn't find any. Is there any good way to do so, or do I have to write for each platform?

Comment: James Montemagno's MediaPlugin does a great job in providing cross-platform camera support: 
 https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 1):

Check this github project. https://github.com/jlandersen/xamarin-forms-camera

In my project I have used this github project as sample. Windows phone part not working if you use 8.1 version, but I think iOS and Android will working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Xam.Plugin.Media` to use the camera functionality and other functions like Video Capture, Image Chooser, Video Chooser etc.

You can download the plugin using NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media

And here you can find the tutorial for the sam: 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Thank You.